# Inserting Curly Brackets in equations

Tags: math-mode

How do i insert curly brackets for a system of equations. I have my equations already done using the insert math multiline environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you precise what you want to achieve? Perhaps a sketch would be useful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and then explain clearly where you want the curly brackets in that MWE.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  From your description, it sounds like one of these approaches might be what you're looking for: `cases` (`amsmath`), `rcases` (`mathtools`), or `systeme` (package of the same name).  All should be described in the relevant documentation, usually accessible by `texdoc <package-name>`.

Comment: You wrote that you use a math environment called `multiline`. Did you maybe intend to write `multline`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico -- I think that "multiline" here means "multi-line", or a display block with more than one line, not specifically the `multline` environment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I think you're right -- and that this query has little to do with TeX, LaTeX, and friends.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  c \colon \{1, \dots, n\} \rightarrow \{1, \dots, n\} \text{ such that}\\      
  c(a_i) = a_{i+1}  \text{ for $1\le i<l$}\\
  c(a_l) = a_1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```